# Ask user to input date in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, datepicker

I am very new to Eclipse, and I am trying to make a basic diary as an android application project. I want to ask user to input the date using a date picker and save it in a variable(s). Please guide me how to achieve it? Thank you so much.

I tried in google but did not find precisely what I am looking for.

Comment: You have not mentioned which language you are trying to achieve this in and I cannot help you without knowing the language. Please update the question Tags which the language :)

Comment: Eclipse is just the tool you use to develop programs and can be used with many different programming languages. So which programming language is this?

Comment: Please, consider first google it and try some example and post here the doubt and difficult you are having in implement the code. Normally the people here don't give the fish, they use to teach to fish ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using Eclipse to develop Java-Applications. (well you tagged android =) )

Check the DatePicker-class 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html

Here you got a small Example on How to use it: 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_datepicker_control.htm

I hope that i understood your question right and you´re helped for now ;)